Error when using Kotlin callbackFlow: pid: 11101, tid: 12001, name: DefaultDispatch >>> com.home.myapp <<<
I'm encountering an error in my Kotlin code while using callback flows, and I'm seeking some guidance on how to resolve it.
I have a Kotlin coroutine function initializeCameraFrameCallback() that creates a callback flow emitting ByteBuffer objects whenever a camera frame is received.
CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
            initializeCameraFrameCallback(camera).buffer(2, BufferOverflow.DROP_OLDEST)
                .collect {
                    if (SettingsScreen.ImageClassificationButton.isON) {
                        initiateImageClassificationProcess(it)
                    }
                }
        }

initializeCameraFrameCallback:
private fun initializeCameraFrameCallback(camera: UVCCamera): Flow<ByteBuffer> = callbackFlow {
        try {
        camera.setFrameCallback(
            { frame ->
                //Sending each frame to a usbVideoSourceListener to display the live feed on a View.
                usbVideoSourceListener?.onNewFrame(
                    VideoSourceListener.FrameHolder.ByteBufferHolder(frame),
                    ImageFormat.RGBA,
                    CAMERA_FRAME_SIZE
                )
               //trySending a frame to our collector.
                trySend(frame)
            },
            UVCCamera.PIXEL_FORMAT_RGBX
        )
        } catch (e:Exception) {}

        awaitClose { channel.close() }
    }

initiateImageClassificationProcess() contains few functions out which the main function is convertByteBufferToImage:
private fun convertByteBufferToImage(frameBuffer: ByteBuffer): Bitmap {
        var frameBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(1024, 576, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
        frameBuffer?.rewind()
        frameBitmap.copyPixelsFromBuffer(frameBuffer)
        ........... Passes the frameBitmap to a tensorflow lite model.
    }

Additional Error logs:
crash_dump64                         A        #09 pc 000000000000dea8  /data/data/com.home.myapp/code_cache/.overlay/base.apk/classes5.dex (com.home.myapp.ImageClassification.convertByteBufferToImage+0)
crash_dump64                         A        #14 pc 000000000000df34  /data/data/com.home.myapp/code_cache/.overlay/base.apk/classes5.dex (com.home.myapp.ImageClassification.getFloodPredictions+0)
crash_dump64                         A        #19 pc 000000000000bbc8  /data/data/com.home.myapp/code_cache/.overlay/base.apk/classes5.dex (com.home.myapp.MainActivity.initiateImageClassificationProcess+0)
crash_dump64                         A        #24 pc 000000000000aed8  /data/data/com.home.myapp/code_cache/.overlay/base.apk/classes5.dex (com.home.myapp.MainActivity.access$initiateImageClassificationProcess+0)
crash_dump64                         A        #29 pc 0000000000009d64  /data/data/com.home.myapp/code_cache/.overlay/base.apk/classes5.dex (com.home.myapp.MainActivity$initiateFrameCallback$1$invokeSuspend$$inlined$collect$1.emit+0)
crash_dump64                         A        #34 pc 000000000176e6c0  /data/app/~~oHGntbsyp2gKiSlnNgiXjg==/com.home.myapp-n5oxScVgaYw3agwVG_eADg==/oat/arm64/base.vdex (kotlinx.coroutines.flow.FlowKt__ChannelsKt.emitAllImpl$FlowKt__ChannelsKt+0)
crash_dump64                         A        #39 pc 000000000176e674  /data/app/~~oHGntbsyp2gKiSlnNgiXjg==/com.home.myapp-n5oxScVgaYw3agwVG_eADg==/oat/arm64/base.vdex (kotlinx.coroutines.flow.FlowKt__ChannelsKt.access$emitAllImpl$FlowKt__ChannelsKt+0)
crash_dump64                         A        #44 pc 000000000176e624  /data/app/~~oHGntbsyp2gKiSlnNgiXjg==/com.home.myapp-n5oxScVgaYw3agwVG_eADg==/oat/arm64/base.vdex (kotlinx.coroutines.flow.FlowKt__ChannelsKt$emitAllImpl$1.invokeSuspend+0)
crash_dump64                         A        #54 pc 000000000178d7a0  /data/app/~~oHGntbsyp2gKiSlnNgiXjg==/com.home.myapp-n5oxScVgaYw3agwVG_eADg==/oat/arm64/base.vdex (kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.runSafely+0)
crash_dump64                         A        #59 pc 000000000178c484  /data/app/~~oHGntbsyp2gKiSlnNgiXjg==/com.home.myapp-n5oxScVgaYw3agwVG_eADg==/oat/arm64/base.vdex (kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.executeTask+0)
crash_dump64                         A        #64 pc 000000000178c59c  /data/app/~~oHGntbsyp2gKiSlnNgiXjg==/com.home.myapp-n5oxScVgaYw3agwVG_eADg==/oat/arm64/base.vdex (kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.runWorker+0)
crash_dump64                         A        #69 pc 000000000178c584  /data/app/~~oHGntbsyp2gKiSlnNgiXjg==/com.home.myapp-n5oxScVgaYw3agwVG_eADg==/oat/arm64/base.vdex (kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.run+0)

Edit 1:
Additional back stack trace:
05-03 15:13:21.327 18636 18636 F DEBUG   : pid: 17568, tid: 18263, name: DefaultDispatch  >>> com.home.myapp <<<
05-03 15:13:21.327 18636 18636 F DEBUG   : uid: 10331
05-03 15:13:21.327 18636 18636 F DEBUG   : signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x0000007239e1d000
05-03 15:13:21.327 18636 18636 F DEBUG   :     x0  000000712eb61ff0  x1  0000007239e1cff0  x2  0000000000151fb0  x3  000000712ec4ffb0
05-03 15:13:21.327 18636 18636 F DEBUG   :     x4  0000007239f6eff0  x5  000000712eda1ff0  x6  ff7c7f7cff7c7f7c  x7  ff7c7f7cff7c7f7c
05-03 15:13:21.327 18636 18636 F DEBUG   :     x8  ff7d807dff7d807d  x9  ff7d807dff7d807d  x10 ff7c7f7cff7d807d  x11 ff7e7e7cff7e7e7c
05-03 15:13:21.327 18636 18636 F DEBUG   :     x12 ffdccfc1ffdbcec0  x13 ffdccec3ffdccec3  x14 00000000705f4651  x15 00000000ebad6a89
05-03 15:13:21.327 18636 18636 F DEBUG   :     x16 00000075844276b8  x17 0000007574e180e0  x18 0000000000000002  x19 0000007239d2eff0
05-03 15:13:21.327 18636 18636 F DEBUG   :     x20 000000712eb61ff0  x21 00000073069291b0  x22 000000719fb6f000  x23 000000719fb6a560
05-03 15:13:21.327 18636 18636 F DEBUG   :     x24 0000007251daff00  x25 000000719fb6a728  x26 0000000050380001  x27 000000000000002c
05-03 15:13:21.327 18636 18636 F DEBUG   :     x28 000000719fb6a620  x29 000000719fb6a5d0
05-03 15:13:21.328 18636 18636 F DEBUG   :     lr  0000007583e100b0  sp  000000719fb6a560  pc  0000007574e18084  pst 0000000020001000
05-03 15:13:21.328 18636 18636 F DEBUG   : backtrace:
05-03 15:13:21.328 18636 18636 F DEBUG   :       #00 pc 000000000004e084  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (__memcpy+276) (BuildId: 2938f6235116cbc48464ee0f7622625e)
05-03 15:13:21.328 18636 18636 F DEBUG   :       #01 pc 00000000002100ac  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (Bitmap_copyPixelsFromBuffer(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*, long, _jobject*)+156) (BuildId: 136fd5097a214bd142443f6328a90d93)
05-03 15:13:21.328 18636 18636 F DEBUG   :       #02 pc 0000000000351e30  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_generic_jni_trampoline+144) (BuildId: 7ece79c15d80914c83e60c9e93ac1684)
05-03 15:13:21.328 18636 18636 F DEBUG   :       #03 pc 00000000005b911c  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (nterp_helper+1948) (BuildId: 7ece79c15d80914c83e60c9e93ac1684)
05-03 15:13:21.328 18636 18636 F DEBUG   :       #04 pc 000000000044c43e  /system/framework/framework.jar (android.graphics.Bitmap.copyPixelsFromBuffer+90)
05-03 15:13:21.328 18636 18636 F DEBUG   :       #05 pc 000000000033b3a4  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub+612) (BuildId: 7ece79c15d80914c83e60c9e93ac1684)
05-03 15:13:21.328 18636 18636 F DEBUG   :       #06 pc 0000000000511590  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, bool, art::JValue*)+1976) (BuildId: 7ece79c15d80914c83e60c9e93ac1684)
05-03 15:13:21.328 18636 18636 F DEBUG   :       #07 pc 0000000000490ffc  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (void art::interpreter::ExecuteSwitchImplCpp<false>(art::interpreter::SwitchImplContext*)+1012) (BuildId: 7ece79c15d80914c83e60c9e93ac1684)
05-03 15:13:21.328 18636 18636 F DEBUG   :       #08 pc 00000000003545d8  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (ExecuteSwitchImplAsm+8) (BuildId: 7ece79c15d80914c83e60c9e93ac1684)
05-03 15:13:21.328 18636 18636 F DEBUG   :       #09 pc 000000000000ddac  /data/data/com.home.myapp/code_cache/.overlay/base.apk/classes5.dex (com.home.myapp.ImageClassification.convertByteBufferToImage+0)
05-03 15:13:21.328 18636 18636 F DEBUG   :       #10 pc 000000000036e6ec  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::interpreter::Execute(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame&, art::JValue, bool, bool) (.__uniq.112435418011751916792819755956732575238.llvm.9545667076320299271)+232) (BuildId: 7ece79c15d80914c83e60c9e93ac1684)
05-03 15:13:21.328 18636 18636 F DEBUG   :       #11 pc 000000000051225c  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, bool, art::JValue*)+5252) (BuildId: 7ece79c15d80914c83e60c9e93ac1684)
05-03 15:13:21.328 18636 18636 F DEBUG   :       #12 pc 0000000000491434  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (void art::interpreter::ExecuteSwitchImplCpp<false>(art::interpreter::SwitchImplContext*)+2092) (BuildId: 7ece79c15d80914c83e60c9e93ac1684)
05-03 15:13:21.328 18636 18636 F DEBUG   :       #13 pc 00000000003545d8  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (ExecuteSwitchImplAsm+8) (BuildId: 7ece79c15d80914c83e60c9e93ac1684)
05-03 15:13:21.328 18636 18636 F DEBUG   :       #14 pc 000000000000de68  /data/data/com.home.myapp/code_cache/.overlay/base.apk/classes5.dex (com.home.myapp.ImageClassification.getFloodPredictions+0)
05-03 15:13:21.328 18636 18636 F DEBUG   :       #15 pc 000000000036e6ec  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::interpreter::Execute(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame&, art::JValue, bool, bool) (.__uniq.112435418011751916792819755956732575238.llvm.9545667076320299271)+232) (BuildId: 7ece79c15d80914c83e60c9e93ac1684)
05-03 15:13:21.328 18636 18636 F DEBUG   :       #16 pc 000000000051225c  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, bool, art::JValue*)+5252) (BuildId: 7ece79c15d80914c83e60c9e93ac1684)
05-03 15:13:21.328 18636 18636 F DEBUG   :       #17 pc 0000000000490ffc  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (void art::interpreter::ExecuteSwitchImplCpp<false>(art::interpreter::SwitchImplContext*)+1012) (BuildId: 7ece79c15d80914c83e60c9e93ac1684)
05-03 15:13:21.328 18636 18636 F DEBUG   :       #18 pc 00000000003545d8  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (ExecuteSwitchImplAsm+8) (BuildId: 7ece79c15d80914c83e60c9e93ac1684)
05-03 15:13:21.328 18636 18636 F DEBUG   :       #19 pc 000000000000baf8  /data/data/com.home.myapp/code_cache/.overlay/base.apk/classes5.dex (com.home.myapp.MainActivity.initiateImageClassificationProcess+0)
05-03 15:13:21.328 18636 18636 F DEBUG   :       #20 pc 000000000036e6ec  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::interpreter::Execute(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame&, art::JValue, bool, bool) (.__uniq.112435418011751916792819755956732575238.llvm.9545667076320299271)+232) (BuildId: 7ece79c15d80914c83e60c9e93ac1684)
05-03 15:13:21.328 18636 18636 F DEBUG   :       #21 pc 000000000051225c  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, bool, art::JValue*)+5252) (BuildId: 7ece79c15d80914c83e60c9e93ac1684)
05-03 15:13:21.328 18636 18636 F DEBUG   :       #22 pc 0000000000491434  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (void art::interpreter::ExecuteSwitchImplCpp<false>(art::interpreter::SwitchImplContext*)+2092) (BuildId: 7ece79c15d80914c83e60c9e93ac1684)
05-03 15:13:21.328 18636 18636 F DEBUG   :       #23 pc 00000000003545d8  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (ExecuteSwitchImplAsm+8) (BuildId: 7ece79c15d80914c83e60c9e93ac1684)
05-03 15:13:21.328 18636 18636 F DEBUG   :       #24 pc 000000000000ae84  /data/data/com.home.myapp/code_cache/.overlay/base.apk/classes5.dex (com.home.myapp.MainActivity.access$initiateImageClassificationProcess+0)
05-03 15:13:21.328 18636 18636 F DEBUG   :       #25 pc 000000000036e6ec  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::interpreter::Execute(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame&, art::JValue, bool, bool) (.__uniq.112435418011751916792819755956732575238.llvm.9545667076320299271)+232) (BuildId: 7ece79c15d80914c83e60c9e93ac1684)
05-03 15:13:21.328 18636 18636 F DEBUG   :       #26 pc 000000000051225c  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, bool, art::JValue*)+5252) (BuildId: 7ece79c15d80914c83e60c9e93ac1684)
05-03 15:13:21.328 18636 18636 F DEBUG   :       #27 pc 000000000049136c  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (void art::interpreter::ExecuteSwitchImplCpp<false>(art::interpreter::SwitchImplContext*)+1892) (BuildId: 7ece79c15d80914c83e60c9e93ac1684)
05-03 15:13:21.328 18636 18636 F DEBUG   :       #28 pc 00000000003545d8  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (ExecuteSwitchImplAsm+8) (BuildId: 7ece79c15d80914c83e60c9e93ac1684)
05-03 15:13:21.328 18636 18636 F DEBUG   :       #29 pc 0000000000009df0  /data/data/com.home.myapp/code_cache/.overlay/base.apk/classes5.dex (com.home.myapp.MainActivity$initiateFrameCallback$1$invokeSuspend$$inlined$collect$1.emit+0)
05-03 15:13:21.328 18636 18636 F DEBUG   :       #30 pc 000000000036e6ec  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::interpreter::Execute(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame&, art::JValue, bool, bool) (.__uniq.112435418011751916792819755956732575238.llvm.9545667076320299271)+232) (BuildId: 7ece79c15d80914c83e60c9e93ac1684)
05-03 15:13:21.328 18636 18636 F DEBUG   :       #31 pc 000000000051225c  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, bool, art::JValue*)+5252) (BuildId: 7ece79c15d80914c83e60c9e93ac1684)
05-03 15:13:21.328 18636 18636 F DEBUG   :       #32 pc 0000000000491eac  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (void art::interpreter::ExecuteSwitchImplCpp<false>(art::interpreter::SwitchImplContext*)+4772) (BuildId: 7ece79c15d80914c83e60c9e93ac1684)
05-03 15:13:21.328 18636 18636 F DEBUG   :       #33 pc 00000000003545d8  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (ExecuteSwitchImplAsm+8) (BuildId: 7ece79c15d80914c83e60c9e93ac1684)
05-03 15:13:21.328 18636 18636 F DEBUG   :       #34 pc 000000000023a228  [anon:dalvik-classes9.dex extracted in memory from /data/app/~~2bg7NSeVbKcCnupTP1aaQA==/com.home.myapp-MZyC-LrDcEPrgaYlh75QAg==/base.apk!classes9.dex] (kotlinx.coroutines.flow.FlowKt__ChannelsKt.emitAllImpl$FlowKt__ChannelsKt+0)
05-03 15:13:21.328 18636 18636 F DEBUG   :       #35 pc 000000000036e6ec  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::interpreter::Execute(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame&, art::JValue, bool, bool) (.__uniq.112435418011751916792819755956732575238.llvm.9545667076320299271)+232) (BuildId: 7ece79c15d80914c83e60c9e93ac1684)
05-03 15:13:21.328 18636 18636 F DEBUG   :       #36 pc 000000000051225c  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, bool, art::JValue*)+5252) (BuildId: 7ece79c15d80914c83e60c9e93ac1684)
05-03 15:13:21.328 18636 18636 F DEBUG   :       #37 pc 000000000049136c  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (void art::interpreter::ExecuteSwitchImplCpp<false>(art::interpreter::SwitchImplContext*)+1892) (BuildId: 7ece79c15d80914c83e60c9e93ac1684)
05-03 15:13:21.328 18636 18636 F DEBUG   :       #38 pc 00000000003545d8  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (ExecuteSwitchImplAsm+8) (BuildId: 7ece79c15d80914c83e60c9e93ac1684)
05-03 15:13:21.328 18636 18636 F DEBUG   :       #39 pc 000000000023a1dc  [anon:dalvik-classes9.dex extracted in memory from /data/app/~~2bg7NSeVbKcCnupTP1aaQA==/com.home.myapp-MZyC-LrDcEPrgaYlh75QAg==/base.apk!classes9.dex] (kotlinx.coroutines.flow.FlowKt__ChannelsKt.access$emitAllImpl$FlowKt__ChannelsKt+0)
05-03 15:13:21.328 18636 18636 F DEBUG   :       #40 pc 000000000036e6ec  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::interpreter::Execute(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame&, art::JValue, bool, bool) (.__uniq.112435418011751916792819755956732575238.llvm.9545667076320299271)+232) (BuildId: 7ece79c15d80914c83e60c9e93ac1684)
05-03 15:13:21.328 18636 18636 F DEBUG   :       #41 pc 000000000051225c  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, bool, art::JValue*)+5252) (BuildId: 7ece79c15d80914c83e60c9e93ac1684)
05-03 15:13:21.328 18636 18636 F DEBUG   :       #42 pc 000000000049136c  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (void art::interpreter::ExecuteSwitchImplCpp<false>(art::interpreter::SwitchImplContext*)+1892) (BuildId: 7ece79c15d80914c83e60c9e93ac1684)
05-03 15:13:21.328 18636 18636 F DEBUG   :       #43 pc 00000000003545d8  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (ExecuteSwitchImplAsm+8) (BuildId: 7ece79c15d80914c83e60c9e93ac1684)
05-03 15:13:21.328 18636 18636 F DEBUG   :       #44 pc 000000000023a18c  [anon:dalvik-classes9.dex extracted in memory from /data/app/~~2bg7NSeVbKcCnupTP1aaQA==/com.home.myapp-MZyC-LrDcEPrgaYlh75QAg==/base.apk!classes9.dex] (kotlinx.coroutines.flow.FlowKt__ChannelsKt$emitAllImpl$1.invokeSuspend+0)
05-03 15:13:21.328 18636 18636 F DEBUG   :       #45 pc 000000000036e6ec  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::interpreter::Execute(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame&, art::JValue, bool, bool) (.__uniq.112435418011751916792819755956732575238.llvm.9545667076320299271)+232) (BuildId: 7ece79c15d80914c83e60c9e93ac1684)
05-03 15:13:21.328 18636 18636 F DEBUG   :       #46 pc 000000000051225c  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, bool, art::JValue*)+5252) (BuildId: 7ece79c15d80914c83e60c9e93ac1684)
05-03 15:13:21.328 18636 18636 F DEBUG   :       #47 pc 0000000000490ffc  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (void art::interpreter::ExecuteSwitchImplCpp<false>(art::interpreter::SwitchImplContext*)+1012) (BuildId: 7ece79c15d80914c83e60c9e93ac1684)
05-03 15:13:21.328 18636 18636 F DEBUG   :       #48 pc 00000000003545d8  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (ExecuteSwitchImplAsm+8) (BuildId: 7ece79c15d80914c83e60c9e93ac1684)
05-03 15:13:21.328 18636 18636 F DEBUG   :       #49 pc 00000000001dddf0  [anon:dalvik-classes9.dex extracted in memory from /data/app/~~2bg7NSeVbKcCnupTP1aaQA==/com.home.myapp-MZyC-LrDcEPrgaYlh75QAg==/base.apk!classes9.dex] (kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith+0)
05-03 15:13:21.328 18636 18636 F DEBUG   :       #50 pc 000000000036e6ec  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::interpreter::Execute(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame&, art::JValue, bool, bool) (.__uniq.112435418011751916792819755956732575238.llvm.9545667076320299271)+232) (BuildId: 7ece79c15d80914c83e60c9e93ac1684)
05-03 15:13:21.328 18636 18636 F DEBUG   :       #51 pc 000000000036dfe4  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (artQuickToInterpreterBridge+964) (BuildId: 7ece79c15d80914c83e60c9e93ac1684)
05-03 15:13:21.328 18636 18636 F DEBUG   :       #52 pc 0000000000351f68  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_to_interpreter_bridge+88) (BuildId: 7ece79c15d80914c83e60c9e93ac1684)
05-03 15:13:21.328 18636 18636 F DEBUG   :       #53 pc 000000000206f988  /memfd:jit-cache (deleted) (kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run+2024)
05-03 15:13:21.328 18636 18636 F DEBUG   :       #54 pc 000000000033b3a4  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub+612) (BuildId: 7ece79c15d80914c83e60c9e93ac1684)
05-03 15:13:21.328 18636 18636 F DEBUG   :       #55 pc 0000000000511590  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, bool, art::JValue*)+1976) (BuildId: 7ece79c15d80914c83e60c9e93ac1684)
05-03 15:13:21.328 18636 18636 F DEBUG   :       #56 pc 0000000000490ffc  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (void art::interpreter::ExecuteSwitchImplCpp<false>(art::interpreter::SwitchImplContext*)+1012) (BuildId: 7ece79c15d80914c83e60c9e93ac1684)
05-03 15:13:21.328 18636 18636 F DEBUG   :       #57 pc 00000000003545d8  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (ExecuteSwitchImplAsm+8) (BuildId: 7ece79c15d80914c83e60c9e93ac1684)
05-03 15:13:21.328 18636 18636 F DEBUG   :       #58 pc 0000000000259308  [anon:dalvik-classes9.dex extracted in memory from /data/app/~~2bg7NSeVbKcCnupTP1aaQA==/com.home.myapp-MZyC-LrDcEPrgaYlh75QAg==/base.apk!classes9.dex] (kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.runSafely+0)
05-03 15:13:21.328 18636 18636 F DEBUG   :       #59 pc 000000000036e6ec  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::interpreter::Execute(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame&, art::JValue, bool, bool) (.__uniq.112435418011751916792819755956732575238.llvm.9545667076320299271)+232) (BuildId: 7ece79c15d80914c83e60c9e93ac1684)
05-03 15:13:21.328 18636 18636 F DEBUG   :       #60 pc 000000000051225c  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, bool, art::JValue*)+5252) (BuildId: 7ece79c15d80914c83e60c9e93ac1684)
05-03 15:13:21.328 18636 18636 F DEBUG   :       #61 pc 0000000000490ffc  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (void art::interpreter::ExecuteSwitchImplCpp<false>(art::interpreter::SwitchImplContext*)+1012) (BuildId: 7ece79c15d80914c83e60c9e93ac1684)
05-03 15:13:21.328 18636 18636 F DEBUG   :       #62 pc 00000000003545d8  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (ExecuteSwitchImplAsm+8) (BuildId: 7ece79c15d80914c83e60c9e93ac1684)
05-03 15:13:21.328 18636 18636 F DEBUG   :       #63 pc 0000000000257fec  [anon:dalvik-classes9.dex extracted in memory from /data/app/~~2bg7NSeVbKcCnupTP1aaQA==/com.home.myapp-MZyC-LrDcEPrgaYlh75QAg==/base.apk!classes9.dex] (kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.executeTask+0)
05-03 15:13:21.328 18636 18636 F DEBUG   :       #64 pc 000000000036e6ec  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::interpreter::Execute(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame&, art::JValue, bool, bool) (.__uniq.112435418011751916792819755956732575238.llvm.9545667076320299271)+232) (BuildId: 7ece79c15d80914c83e60c9e93ac1684)
05-03 15:13:21.328 18636 18636 F DEBUG   :       #65 pc 000000000051225c  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, bool, art::JValue*)+5252) (BuildId: 7ece79c15d80914c83e60c9e93ac1684)
05-03 15:13:21.328 18636 18636 F DEBUG   :       #66 pc 0000000000491434  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (void art::interpreter::ExecuteSwitchImplCpp<false>(art::interpreter::SwitchImplContext*)+2092) (BuildId: 7ece79c15d80914c83e60c9e93ac1684)
05-03 15:13:21.328 18636 18636 F DEBUG   :       #67 pc 00000000003545d8  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (ExecuteSwitchImplAsm+8) (BuildId: 7ece79c15d80914c83e60c9e93ac1684)
05-03 15:13:21.328 18636 18636 F DEBUG   :       #68 pc 0000000000258104  [anon:dalvik-classes9.dex extracted in memory from /data/app/~~2bg7NSeVbKcCnupTP1aaQA==/com.home.myapp-MZyC-LrDcEPrgaYlh75QAg==/base.apk!classes9.dex] (kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.runWorker+0)
05-03 15:13:21.328 18636 18636 F DEBUG   :       #69 pc 000000000036e6ec  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::interpreter::Execute(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame&, art::JValue, bool, bool) (.__uniq.112435418011751916792819755956732575238.llvm.9545667076320299271)+232) (BuildId: 7ece79c15d80914c83e60c9e93ac1684)
05-03 15:13:21.328 18636 18636 F DEBUG   :       #70 pc 000000000051225c  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, bool, art::JValue*)+5252) (BuildId: 7ece79c15d80914c83e60c9e93ac1684)
05-03 15:13:21.328 18636 18636 F DEBUG   :       #71 pc 0000000000491434  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (void art::interpreter::ExecuteSwitchImplCpp<false>(art::interpreter::SwitchImplContext*)+2092) (BuildId: 7ece79c15d80914c83e60c9e93ac1684)
05-03 15:13:21.328 18636 18636 F DEBUG   :       #72 pc 00000000003545d8  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (ExecuteSwitchImplAsm+8) (BuildId: 7ece79c15d80914c83e60c9e93ac1684)
05-03 15:13:21.328 18636 18636 F DEBUG   :       #73 pc 00000000002580ec  [anon:dalvik-classes9.dex extracted in memory from /data/app/~~2bg7NSeVbKcCnupTP1aaQA==/com.home.myapp-MZyC-LrDcEPrgaYlh75QAg==/base.apk!classes9.dex] (kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.run+0)
05-03 15:13:21.328 18636 18636 F DEBUG   :       #74 pc 000000000036e6ec  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::interpreter::Execute(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame&, art::JValue, bool, bool) (.__uniq.112435418011751916792819755956732575238.llvm.9545667076320299271)+232) (BuildId: 7ece79c15d80914c83e60c9e93ac1684)
05-03 15:13:21.328 18636 18636 F DEBUG   :       #75 pc 000000000036dfe4  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (artQuickToInterpreterBridge+964) (BuildId: 7ece79c15d80914c83e60c9e93ac1684)
05-03 15:13:21.328 18636 18636 F DEBUG   :       #76 pc 0000000000351f68  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_to_interpreter_bridge+88) (BuildId: 7ece79c15d80914c83e60c9e93ac1684)
05-03 15:13:21.328 18636 18636 F DEBUG   :       #77 pc 000000000033b3a4  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub+612) (BuildId: 7ece79c15d80914c83e60c9e93ac1684)
05-03 15:13:21.328 18636 18636 F DEBUG   :       #78 pc 000000000023a5d0  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, art::JValue*, char const*)+144) (BuildId: 7ece79c15d80914c83e60c9e93ac1684)
05-03 15:13:21.328 18636 18636 F DEBUG   :       #79 pc 0000000000539b2c  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::Thread::CreateCallback(void*)+1600) (BuildId: 7ece79c15d80914c83e60c9e93ac1684)
05-03 15:13:21.328 18636 18636 F DEBUG   :       #80 pc 00000000000ba598  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+208) (BuildId: 2938f6235116cbc48464ee0f7622625e)
05-03 15:13:21.328 18636 18636 F DEBUG   :       #81 pc 0000000000053f3c  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (__start_thread+68) (BuildId: 2938f6235116cbc48464ee0f7622625e)

I tried adding a buffer capacity of 2 and onBufferOverflow.DROP_LATEST to drop the the oldest frame whenever a new frame is received from the callback method but still the crash is happening.
Another method which I've tried is taking 1 out of 5 frames from the setFrameCallback(), ie, keeping count of the frames and when frameCount%5==0, send the frame to the initiateImageClassificationProcess().
When using this method, no crash is observed.
Note: Around 10-12 Frames are produced per second by the setFrameCallback().

Can you please provide the entire stack trace? I'm still not sure which error actually occurred

Thanks for commenting @Leviathan!
I have added additional back trace, kindly have a look.

SIGSEGV is a memory violation; nothing you have done wrong in your code (that also means you cannot fix it), it's probably a bug in some low level library, possibly even the android runtime itself. A cursory search led me to https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/145569946 and https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36917827. There may be some workaround for your code, though. If you condense your code into a minimal reproducible example that can be executed we can have a look.

Thank You @Leviathan, I'll check on the links which you've shared and let you know!
